# Bayesian approach and ML approach for distributions

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, random-variable, posterior, observational-study

Suppose that we have two sets of discrete random variables **X** ~ f(θ), **Y**~g(θ) where **X** and **Y** are independent, and the parameter θ is the same in both cases. We are interested in predicting **Y** on the basis of observations of **X**.

Describe the maximum likelihood approach to predicting features of the distribution of **Y** based on observing that **X**=**x**obs

Describe the Bayesian approach to computing the posterior distribution Pr{**Y**=**y**|**X**=**x**obs}

Comment: maybe you could search this site for "predictive likelihood".

Comment: Is this from a class or a textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its wiki.

Answer (score 0):

For a Bayesian,
$$ p(y|x) = \int p(y|\theta)p(\theta|x) d\theta $$
where we are using the usual posterior for $\theta$ given $x$, i.e. 
$$ p(\theta|x) \propto p(x|\theta)p(\theta).$$

For "Describe the maximum likelihood approach ...", we could use $p(y|\hat{\theta}_{mle})$ where 
$$ \hat{\theta}_{mle} = \sup_{\theta} p(x|\theta) $$
but this does not account for our uncertainty about $\theta$. I know of no way to properly account for this uncertainty in a frequentist paradigm (this doesn't mean it doesn't exist just that I don't know what it is).